# NameError (uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have get error in my attempt to visit page:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Web::Admin::Products::BrandsController::Brand):
app/controllers/web/admin/products/brands_controller.rb:3:in `index'
```

My Controller:

```
app/controllers/web/admin/products/brands_controller.rb
```

My model:

```
app/models/product/brand.rb
```

My routes.rb

```
scope module: :web do

  namespace :admin do
    namespace :products do
      resources :brands     
    end 

    resources :products do
      scope module: :products do          
        resources :product_types
      end      
    end

  end
end
```

My index action `in app/controllers/web/admin/products/brands_controller.rb`

```
def index
    @search = Brand.all
    @brands = @search.result(distinct: true)
end
```

Help me , please

Comment: add to your answer `index` action

Comment: Here is my index action above

Comment: show the first lines of the file `brands_controller.rb`

Comment: try `@search = ::Brand.all`

Comment: first line of the file brands_controller.rb  <br/>                                                                                                             `def index
    @search = Brand.all
    @brands = @search.result(distinct: true)
end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All problem in your namespaces
you have 2 ways for resolve it:

1. rename your model to `Product::Brand`
2. change way to your model:

form `app/models/product/brand.rb`

to `app/models/brand.rb`

Comment: Thanks Oleg, thanks to All. I followed the first way

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use a namespace for your model:
`app/models/product/brand.rb` to `app/models/brand.rb`